# Выборка join codeigniter подсчет строк

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

есть две таблицы

```
blogi
+----+-----------+
| id | blog_cate | 
+----+-----------+
|  1 | database  | 
|  2 | database  |
|  4 | razrabotka| 
+----+-----------+

blog_cate
+----+------------------+---------------+
| id | blogi_cate_title | blogi_cate_url| 
+----+------------------+---------------+
|  1 |  Базы данных     | database      | 
|  2 |  PHP             | php           |
|  3 |  Разработка      | razrabotka    |
+----+----------+-----------------+------
```

Необходимо сделать выборку

чтоб было так

Базы данных 2

Разработка 1

PHP 0

```
$this->db->select('blogi_cate.*, COUNT(blogi.blog_cate) as num');
$this->db->join('blogi', 'blogi.blog_cate = blogi_cate.blogi_cate_url');
$query = $this->db->get('blogi_cate');
```

Работает не корректно только одно совпадения

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[blogi_cate_id] => 3
[blogi_cate_title] => Базы данных
[blogi_cate_url] => database
[num] => 15
)

)
```

Comment: не понятно на счет таблиц, можете представить структуру, как здесь пример например: 

    +----+----------+-----------------+-----------+
    | id | username | email           | password  |
    +----+----------+-----------------+-----------+
    |  1 | Alex     | alex@email.com  | alexpass  |
    |  2 | Max      | max@email.com   | maxpass   |
    |  3 | Denis    | denis@email.com | denispass |
    |  4 | Mark     | mark@email.com  | markpass  |
    +----+----------+-----------------+-----------+

Comment: @2sldie в самом вопросе отформатируйте нормально вместо столбика того что есть.

Comment: Переделал структуру.

Comment: так:

    $this->db->select('blog_cate.*, COUNT(blogi.blog_cate) as num');
    $this->db->join('blogi','blogi.blog_cate=blog_cate.blogi_cate_url');
    $this->db->group_by('blogi.blog_cate');
    $query = $this->db->get('blog_cate');

Comment: Спасибо работает)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Smash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5512)*

Необходимо добавить группировку по `blogi.blog_cate`

```
<?php
$this->db->select('blog_cate.*, COUNT(blogi.blog_cate) as num');
$this->db->join('blogi','blogi.blog_cate=blog_cate.blogi_cate_url'); 
$this->db->group_by('blogi.blog_cate');
$query = $this->db->get('blog_cate');
```